# Error while pdf parsing PyPDF2 and textract

Tags: python, for-loop, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to build a program that looks for specific words or short phrases in a pdf file. The files load well but I have a problem when searching through the pdf, when the page changes. Here's my code:

```
import PyPDF2
import glob, os, shutil
import textract

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\patent")
goodfiles=[]
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    pdfFileObj = open(file, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj, strict=False)

    search_word_main = "isophthalic"
    word_main=[]
    search_word_sub = ["acid index", "acid value", "acid number", "acidity index","acidity"]
    word_sub=[]
    for pageNum in range(1, pdfReader.numPages):
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
        text = pageObj.extractText().encode('utf-8')
        search_text = text.lower().split()
        toprange=len(search_text)-1

        for len in range (toprange):
           if search_word_main in search_text[len].decode("utf-8"):
                print(search_word_main)
           for key in search_word_sub:
                if key in search_text[len].decode("utf-8") + " " + search_text[len+1].decode("utf-8"):
                    print(key)
```

on the first page of the pdf, everything works well, but, whenever it moves to the second page, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    toprange=len(search_text)-1
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I don't understand why whenever the page changes, this happens. If I just try to print the toprange variable rather than adding it to the loop, there's no problem and I get the values for toprange. There seems to be a problem with the for loop but I don't seem to find where. Could you help me solve this?

Thanks in advance.